# How can I check if an input is NaN?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check to see if an input is NaN, basically I want to alert 0 if nums doesn't have anything in it, or if that something is a 0. Any ideas on how to go about this?

```
var sumofnums = 0,
nums = document.getElementById("nums").value.split(",");

function add(){
    for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        sumofnums += parseInt(nums[i]);
    };
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sumofnums;
};
if (nums === ''){
    alert('0');
}
```

Comment: So do the paring into a variable and check if the variable is NaN....

Comment: Ask it.  `isNaN(numVariable)`

Comment: @epascarello can you show me an example of this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: @RandyCasburn so if (isNAN(nums))?

Comment: Well, it is a little more complicated. You are splitting the input at the comma, but you cannot guarantee that a comma will be used. So there may be other issues. Now, to your question: no, you cannot pass `nums` into `isNaN()` because it is an array. You would pass each of the `nums` elements.

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes and also I noticed that since there are commas it will register as NaN

Answer (score -1):

isNaN();

Google can help as well.

Comment: Tried this and not as easy as you make it seem